# How to filter out characters that aren't letters, numbers or punctuation

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string that will have a lot of formatting things like bullet points or arrows or whatever. I want to clean this string so that it only contains letters, numbers and punctuation. Multiple spaces should be replaced by a single space too.

Allowed punctuation: `, . : ; [ ] ( ) / \ ! @ # $ % ^ & * + - _ { } < > = ? ~ | "`

Basically anything allowed in [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ioaq100/ascii_table.gif) ASCII table.

This is what I have so far:

```
let asciiOnly = y.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/gm, '')
let withoutSpacing = asciiOnly.replace(/\s{2,}/gm, ' ')
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/0DC1tz/2

I also tried the `[:punct:]` tag but apparently it's not supported by javascript. Is there a better way I can clean this string other than regex? A library or something maybe (I didn't find any). If not, how would I do this with regex? Would I have to edit the first regex to add every single character of punctuation?

EDIT: I'm trying to paste an example string in the question but SO just removes characters it doesn't recognize so it looks like a normal string. [Heres a paste](https://pastebin.com/05zfKE4x).

EDIT2: I think this is what I needed:

```
let asciiOnly = x.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]+/gm, '')
let withoutSpacing = asciiOnly.replace(/\s{2,}/gm, ' ')
```

I'm testing it with different cases to make sure.

Comment: you put it on drive or something like that so that others can see

Comment: You have to be more clear about what you exactly want to keep and to remove: take a look at the ascii table (and eventually at the unicode table) and reformulate your question.

Comment: What means "normal" string? Does it include newline?

Comment: It's unknown what you consider 'punctuation' and what not. Should exotic quote marks that don't exist in ASCII be kept? Should `$` and `&` be kept? It's not punctuation char at all. I assume that only you know exactly which symbols you need. So you need to list them.

Comment: @estus I just meant any character you would usually see in text. Updated the question.

Comment: @ninesalt: Will it be okay if we retain all characters that fall in ASCII range and remove rest?

Comment: Why don't you just ignore any non ASCII char? [^\x00-\x7F]+

Comment: Using an ASCII filter could possibly be made to work, but, just as an example, should a BEL character be allowed?

Comment: @boy that doesn't work. Check the regex101 link.

Comment: @shapeofmatter No.

Comment: Do you mean that infinity char is allowed?

Comment: @boy Oh my bad. No it shouldn't be allowed. The regex is wrong.

Comment: FYI you can shorten your regex a bit by using `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. This also translates nicely if you decide to use a Unicode regex instead, as it will match all Unicode alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Perhaps `yourstr = yourstr.replace(/[^!-~]+/g, ' ').trim()` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @ninesalt Should newline characters be collapsed into spaces as well?

Comment: @mc10 Yes they should.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using below regex, which finds any non-ascii characters (also excludes non-printable ascii characters and excluding extended ascii too) and removes it with empty string.

```
[^ -~]+
```

This is assuming you want to retain all printable ASCII characters only, which range from space (ascii value 32) to tilde `~` hence usage of this char set `[^ !-~]`

And then replaces all one or more white space with a single space

```js
 var str = `Determine the values of P∞ and E∞ for each of the following signals:  b. 
 d. 
   f. 
Periodic and aperiodic signals Determine whether or not each of the following signals is periodic:
 b. 

Determine whether or not each of the following signals is periodic. If a signal is periodic, specify its fundamental period.
 b. 
 d. 

Transformation of Independent variables A continuous-time signal x(t) is shown in Figure 1. Sketch and label carefully each of the following signals:
   b.  c. 
d.     e.     f.  Figure 1: Problem Set 1.4
Even and Odd Signals
For each signal given below, determine all the values of the independent variable at which the even part of the signal is guaranteed to be zero.
 b. 
 d.  -------------------------`;

console.log(str.replace(/[^ -~]+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g, ' '));   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
console.log(str.replace(/[^ !-~]+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

Also, if you just want to allow all alphanumeric characters and mentioned special characters, then you can use this regex to first retain all needed characters using this regex ,

```
[^ a-zA-Z0-9,.:;[\]()/\!@#$%^&*+_{}<>=?~|"-]+
```

Replace this with empty string and then replace one or more white spaces with just a single space.

```js
var str = `Determine the values of P∞ and E∞ for each of the following signals:  b. 
     d. 
       f. 
    Periodic and aperiodic signals Determine whether or not each of the following signals is periodic:
     b. 
    
    Determine whether or not each of the following signals is periodic. If a signal is periodic, specify its fundamental period.
     b. 
     d. 
    
    Transformation of Independent variables A continuous-time signal x(t) is shown in Figure 1. Sketch and label carefully each of the following signals:
       b.  c. 
    d.     e.     f.  Figure 1: Problem Set 1.4
    Even and Odd Signals
    For each signal given below, determine all the values of the independent variable at which the even part of the signal is guaranteed to be zero.
     b. 
     d.  -------------------------`;

console.log(str.replace(/[^ a-zA-Z0-9,.:;[\]()/\!@#$%^&*+_{}<>=?~|"-]+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g, ' '));
```

Comment: I think your regex replaces too many spaces; e.g. `P∞ and` turned into `Pand`.

Comment: `console.log("Test∞ 123".replace(/( ) *|[^!-~]+/g,'$1'));` prints `Test123`, which seems incorrect.

Comment: @mc10: Yes space got missed in char set. Let me update the regex.

Comment: This is nice and clean, but doesn't quite match the whitespace handling in the original question. In addition to the question of what to do with exotic unicode spaces, this regex won't handle newlines or tabs. While the question didn't request anything specific for them, the starting regex in the question suggests the intention was to replace them all with ` `.

Comment: Yeah, something like `console.log("Test ∞ ∞ ° 123".replace(/( ) *|[^ !-~]+/g, '$1'));` prints `Test    123` (4 spaces), which doesn't collapse all of the spaces down to a single space.

Comment: Check now. Have changed the approach. First all non-ascii removed then multiple whitespaces are replaced with a single space.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i will do. I will remove the all the non allowed character first and than replace the multiple spaces with a single space.

```js
let str = `Determine the values of P∞ and E∞ for each of the following signals:  b. 
 d. 
 f. 
Periodic and aperiodic signals Determine whether or not each of the following signals is periodic:!!!23
 b. 

Determine whether or not each of the following signals is periodic. If a signal is periodic, specify its fundamental period.
 b. 
 d. 

Transformation of Independent variables A continuous-time signal x(t) is shown in Figure 1. Sketch and label carefully each of the following signals:
 b.  c. 
d.  e.  f.  Figure 1: Problem Set 1.4
Even and Odd Signals
For each signal given below, determine all the values of the independent variable at which the even part of the signal is guaranteed to be zero.
 b. 
 d.  ------------------------- `

const op = str.replace(/[^\w,.:;\[\]()/\!@#$%^&*+{}<>=?~|" -]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, " ")

console.log(op)
```

**EDIT** : In case you want to keep `\n` or `\t` as it is use `(\s)\1+, "$1"` in second regex.

Comment: I think this is the correct approach, but the whitespace regex should be just `\s+`, I'm pretty sure. Also, I think you don't need to include `_` in the list of allowed characters; I think it's included in `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

- There probably isn't a better solution than a regex. The under-the-hood implementation of regex actions is usually well optimized by virtue of age and ubiquity.
- You *may* be able to explicitly tell the regex handler to "compile" the regex. This is usually a good idea if you know the regex is going to be used a lot within a program, and *may* help with performance here. But I don't know if javascript exposes such an option.
- The idea of "normal punctuation" doesn't have an excellent foundation. There are some common marks like "90°" that aren't ASCII, and some ASCII marks like "" (`&#127;`) that you almost certainly *don't* want. I would expect you to find similar edge cases with any pre-made list. In any case, just explicitly listing all the punctuation you want to allow is *better in general*, because then no one will ever have to look up what's in the list you chose.
- You *may* be able to perform both substitutions in a single pass, but it's unclear if that will perform better and it almost certainly won't be clearer to any co-workers (including yourself-from-the-future). There will be a lot of finicky details to work out such as whether `" ° "` should be replaced with `""`, `" "`, or `"  "`.